# AdaptivePayments error

Tags: php, paypal

I wrote a script more than a year ago to send automatic payments using the AdaptivePayments api. It worked fine till october 25th when I started getting this message:

This+transaction+cannot+be+processed.+Please+enter+a+valid+credit+card+number+and+type

Our company paypal account is linked to a bank account and 3 credit cards. Before said date, every time a payment was requested, if no money was available, paypal took the money from the bank account sending the payment as echeck. It seems like now it's not happening anymore.

The script is in php and these are the parameters I'm sending:

```
"requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US", 
"actionType" => "PAY",
"senderEmail" => OUR_EMAIL,
"receiverList.receiver(0).email" => RECEIVER,
"receiverList.receiver(0).amount" => AMOUNT,
"currencyCode" => "CAD",
"feesPayer" => "EACHRECEIVER",
"memo" => MEMO,
"ipnNotificationUrl" => IPNURL,
"cancelUrl" => CANCELURL,
"returnUrl" => RETURNURL
```

and these are the parameters I'm completing the call with:

```
$params = array("http" => 
            array("method" => "POST",
                "content" => $body_data,
                "header" =>  
                    "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" . 
                    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: " . $API_UserName . "\r\n" .                                                                     
                    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: " . $API_Password . "\r\n" .                                                                                   
                    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: " . $API_Signature . "\r\n" .                 
                    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_RequestFormat . "\r\n" .
                    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_ResponseFormat . "\r\n" .
                    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: " . $API_AppID . "\r\n"
            )
        );
```

Do you see anything wrong?
Thanks

Example response:

This is an actual response:
{"responseEnvelope.timestamp":"2013-11-05T08%3A46%3A48.186-08%3A00","responseEnvelope.ack":"Success","responseEnvelope.correlationId":"c1ad6cc6e9574","responseEnvelope.build":"7935900","payKey":"AP-1A056988AE1232421","paymentExecStatus":"ERROR","payErrorList.payError(0).receiver.amount":"5","payErrorList.payError(0).receiver.email":"jxykk%40hotmail.com","payErrorList.payError(0).error.errorId":"580036","payErrorList.payError(0).error.domain":"PLATFORM","payErrorList.payError(0).error.severity":"Error","payErrorList.payError(0).error.category":"Application","payErrorList.payError(0).error.message":"This+transaction+cannot+be+processed.+Please+enter+a+valid+credit+card+number+and+type"}

Comment: Have you checked PayPal documents for recent changes - they do occasionally update their services and break things in the process.

Comment: That's an odd error to be getting with the Adaptive Payments API.  Can you post a sample of your actual API request and response instead of the code that generates it?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely sure it worked before check what version of the API was it. You can explicitly specify (and should ) which version api you want in headers.

Comment: See, the problem is that sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. Yesterday for instance it worked for less than 1% of the transactions, so it was a disaster. Today so far it worked for all transactions (38) except for 3. Which is better than yesterday, but still, I don't understand why those 3 wouldn't go through.